# working encryption but won't decrypt

Tags: php

My First post!  I've been trying to learn encryption and my efforts seem to be hitting a wall when it comes to decryption.  My function encrypts fine it just won't decrypt!

Thanks PHP Addict

```
function encrypt_data($Key, $Secret, $Mode){
    $Key = "$Key";
    $Data = "$Secret";
    $Mode = strtolower("$Mode");

    srand((double)microtime()*1000000 );
    $td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, '', MCRYPT_MODE_CFB, '');
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td), MCRYPT_RAND);
    $ks = mcrypt_enc_get_key_size($td);
    $Key = substr(sha1($Key), 0, $ks);

    mcrypt_generic_init($td, $Key, $iv);
    $CypherText = mcrypt_generic($td, $Data);
    mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);

    mcrypt_generic_init($td, $Key, $iv);
    $PlainText = mdecrypt_generic($td, $CypherText);
    mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
    mcrypt_module_close($td);

    if("$Mode" == 'encrypt'){
        return trim($CypherText);
    }

    if("$Mode" == 'decrypt'){
        return trim($PlainText);
    }
}

                                     #debugging code
$Key = 'my secret key';
$Secret = 'my very big secret';

$Hidden = encrypt_data($Key, $Secret, 'encrypt');
print $Hidden;

$ExposeMe = encrypt_data($Key, $Hidden, 'decrypt');

print $ExposeMe;
```

Comment: You should add "\n" : print $Hidden."\n"; and print $Hidden."\n";

Answer (score 0):

Try this, just added base64_encode() and base64_decode() :

```
...
mcrypt_generic_init($td, $Key, $iv);
$CypherText = base64_encode(mcrypt_generic($td, $Data));
mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);

mcrypt_generic_init($td, $Key, $iv);
$PlainText = mdecrypt_generic($td, base64_decode($CypherText));
mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
mcrypt_module_close($td);
...
```

Comment: Thanks Tazeg, I was going to add the base64 encoding later.  However adding the \n to the output variable won't solve the fact that it won't decrypt my "secret."  At the moment the $Hidden is just outputting the same encrypted cypher... PHPAddict